# Refining Highs and Lows

Tags: pine-script

I´m a very beginner in Pine editor, I´m trying to refine my Highs and Lows indicator but I don´t know how to do it. The issue is that I want to get the Highs and Lows but only of those ones whose highs and lows are higher or lower than the previous or next candle, and so on for the 3 left and right candles.
This is what I got so far...

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test_H_L", overlay=true)

leftBars = input(3)
rightBars=input(3)

ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)

plot(ph, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=4, color= color.green, offset=-rightBars)
plot(pl, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=4, color= color.red, offset=-rightBars)
```

Any idea how to do the same but without the offset when plotting?  I need to get the exact points to reference them with an line array. if I use offset the points are different.

Comment: Can you be more precise and edit your question with a chart ? Why ta.pivothigh doesn't fit your problem ?

Comment: Sure. what I would like to plot is only those peaks with high[1]>high[2]  and low[1]< low [2] on both sides, left and right, and now it´s plotting all the peaks that at least have 3 candles on both sides. [link](https://www.tradingview.com/x/GCfrF03g/). See the link for a better explanation. I don´t want to plot the peaks with the red X. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what you can do with matrix. 
 This code detects the peaks which are greater on both side. 
 You can adapt it to get your lows also.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © mentalRock19315

//@version=5
indicator("Test_H_L", overlay=true)

leftBars = input(3)
rightBars=input(3)

ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)

plot(ph, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=4, color= color.green, offset=-rightBars)
plot(pl, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=4, color= color.red, offset=-rightBars)

// matrix.new<float>(rows, columns, initial_value)
// col 0 = index of the high/low
// col 1 = value of the high/low
var MHigh = matrix.new<float>(0, 2, 0.0)
var MLow = matrix.new<float>(0, 2, 0.0)

if not(na(ph))
    matrix.add_row(MHigh)
    // matrix.set(id, row, column, value)
    matrix.set(MHigh, matrix.rows(MHigh)-1, 0, bar_index-rightBars)
    matrix.set(MHigh, matrix.rows(MHigh)-1, 1, ph)
 
hightoplot = 0.0
indextoplot = 0

if matrix.rows(MHigh) > 2 and not(na(ph))
    HighPrevious = matrix.get(MHigh, matrix.rows(MHigh)-3, 1)
    HighCurrent = matrix.get(MHigh, matrix.rows(MHigh)-2, 1)
    HighAfter = matrix.get(MHigh, matrix.rows(MHigh)-1, 1)
    if HighCurrent > HighPrevious and HighCurrent > HighAfter
        hightoplot := HighCurrent
        indextoplot := int(matrix.get(MHigh, matrix.rows(MHigh)-2, 0))
        label.new(indextoplot,hightoplot,color=color.green, style=label.style_diamond, size=size.normal)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is also called fractals.  3 and 5 day fractals are the most commonly used. If your need is different you can adjust the formula to 7-9 days if you want.  Below is what I use.  It is five day fractal / high.  Part of sell signal for me.   I have offset / moved back shape by two bars for you. Hope this helps.

//@version=5

indicator("Sell 5day Fractal",overlay = true)

A=high[3]>high[4]

B=high[2]>high[3]

C=high[1]>high[2]

D=high[1]>high

E=A and B and C and D

plotshape(E,"5 day fractal",style = shape.circle,color = color.red,location = location.abovebar,text="Sell",textcolor = color.black, offset = -2)

Comment: Yeah, something like that is what I want, thanks! Would it be a chance to plot the current TimeFrame instead of just "Sell"?

Comment: I did not understand plot the current time frame.  Above code will pick time frame selected for the chart.  And for buy code, just apply lows logic instead of highs.